# Debian bridge networking restart fail

Tags: networking, debian, bridge

I'm having some difficulties getting my guests to see my host.
When I'm trying to restart my interfaces I'm getting an error.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

returns

```
Reconfiguring network interfaces...if-up.d/mountnfs[eth0]: waiting for interface br0 before doing NFS mounts (warning).
device br0 already exists; can't create bridge with the same name
run-parts: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/bridge exited with return code 1
SIOCADDRT: File exists
Failed to bring up br0.
done.
```

What does this mean?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like a bridge was setup outside of the Debian network scripts.  Try running "brctl delbr br0" to delete the bridge manually.  Then restart networking to see if it brings the bridge up properly.

Steve

Comment: Thanks, Steve. That did the trick. Now I have not errors when restarting my interfaces. I'm still having problems getting my guests to see my host. I'm getting 
Pinging 88.198.52.252 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 88.198.52.250: TTL expired in transit.

Comment: Make sure that you are assigning the IP address to the bridge interface, and not the ethernet interfaces.  Do a "/sbin/ifconfig" to confirm this.  You might want to look at the arp table on the server, and confirm that you are seeing the client's mac address.  The "arp" command should do this on Linux.